# How to show password activity immediately without existing activity getting flashed for few seconds while coming from background?

Tags: android, android-activity, stack, activity-lifecycle, background-foreground

I want to add password screen always at top of stack when app opens from background. I am able to find out method when app comes from background using **ActivityLifecycleCallbacks** or **LifecycleObserver** and can show password screen in `onStart` of base activity. but for few seconds, user see existing activity from where it went to background and then intents to password activity. I want a way so that i can add password activity when app is going to background. but with the methods, i am able to know only when app has already went to background. There is no way that i can add password activity to stack without launching that.

Comment: Try finish(); to close current activity on onPause callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fragments in your BaseActivity:
       Activity Class:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (ifConditionTrue) {
        //Launch whatever fragment you want
    } else {
        addFragment(new PasswordFragment());
    }
}

// Replace current Fragment with the destination Fragment.
public void addFragment(Fragment destFragment) {
    // First get FragmentManager object.
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // Begin Fragment transaction.
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    // Replace the layout holder with the required Fragment object.
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, destFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

    // Commit the Fragment replace action.
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}}
```

base_activity_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".BaseActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
```

Comment: onCreate() of base activity doesnt get called when app comes to foreground and i should not set any layout in base activity.. Even if i do, that would be overridden by child activities